# How to reset the controlgroup pristine state to true after submitting the form?

Tags: angular

I am trying to reset the controlgroup pristine state to true after submitting the form using markAsPristine() ...But its not happening, getting error like this "markAsPristine is not a function"... I dont want to rebuild the form after submit so i just want to make the controlgroup pristine state to true using this markaspristine function(reference https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6679). Here is my demo http://plnkr.co/edit/W8Fs6O6QsMCG1AWhxzqv?p=preview ...

```
onsubmit(){
  console.log(this.model);
  this.model.markAsPristine();
}
```

somebody please tell me where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at [Angular documentation, forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

```
active = true;

  newHero() {
    this.model = new Hero(42, '', '');
    this.active = false;
    setTimeout(()=> this.active=true, 0);
  }
```

then in your template

```
<form *ngIf="active">
```

Which will destroy and recreate the form when active is false.

As mentioned above, this is a temporary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read the original pull request, it was moved to [another pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7288). However, that PR was closed:

> This PR is stale (does not rebase; pass CI; had no activity for a while). It is probably our fault, and we are sorry. In an effort to keep our PR queue under control, and prevent us from taking too long to get back to you we are cleaning up the queue. Unfortunately this means that this PR is getting closed.

So the functionality you are looking for has not been merged and thus not available.

So as you also have mentioned you could for example rebuild the form as you can see [here](https://github.com/ajtowf/ng2_play/blob/master/app/components/todo/todo.ts#L46-L52) .

Here are some other references that this is yet not implemented. For now there are only workarounds:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6169
2. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4933

One suggestion was:

```
onSubmit(value: any): void {
  form.controls.forEach((name, control) => {
    control.updateValue('');
    control.setErrors(null);
  });
}
```

Another way:

```
this.form['_touched'] = false;
StringMapWrapper.forEach(this.form.controls, (control: AbstractControl, name: string) => {
  control['_touched'] = false;
});
```

See the issues on GitHub for workarounds. Other than that there is no built in solution for this yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this, first need to check weather form or model dirty or not.

```
onsubmit(){
  console.log(this.model);
  if (this.model.dirty) {
return confirm('You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to navigate away?');
        }
        return true;
}
```